# Lines parallel/perpendicular in space & Collinear points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to confirm two things :

- In space $(\mathbb{R}^3)$ if line $\ell_1$ is perpendicular to line $\ell_2$ and line $\ell_2$ is perpendicular to line $\ell_3$, then $\ell_1$ is parallel to $\ell_3$.
- The points $A,B,C$ (pairwise different) are collinear iff the vectors $\vec{AB}, \vec{CB}$ are parallel.

I think the first statement is correct due to the direction vectors and the cross product.

I think the second statement is wrong, since we have that these 3 points are collinear iff $AB + BC = AC$, right?

Comment: $x$ axis is perpendicular to $y$ axis which is perpendicular to $z$ axis. $x$ and $z$ are not parallel

Comment: Ahhh yes! So both statement are not true in general,right? @Raffaele

Comment: Or are both always false? @Raffaele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is false

$x$ axis is perpendicular to $y$ axis which is perpendicular to $z$ axis. $x$ and $z$ are not parallel.

The second looks correct.

If $A,B,C$ are collinear, then they lie on the same line and $\vec{AB},\vec{CB}$ are parallel.

If $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{CB}$ are parallel, then there is a scalar $\lambda$ such that

$\vec{AB}=\lambda\vec{CB}$ that is $A=B+\lambda\vec{CB}$ therefore $A,B,C$ are collinear.

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)